# Is the specification for the DistinguishedName certificate_authorities in RFC2246 (TLS) documented anywhere?

Tags: ssl, protocols, x509, asn.1

RFC2246 (the TLS specification) lays out all the data structures for SSL/TLS handshakes (as well as a hell of a lot more that I'm not concerned with right now).  For the certificate_request handshake type, one of the items that gets sent is a list of DistinguishedName objects (certificate_authorities), which is defined in the spec as an opaque (essentially, seems to be a blob).  The spec then says that the DistinguishedName is derived from [X509] - but it doesn't say how close it is, or how it's different.

I'm trying to parse raw certificate_requests handshake messages, and running into trouble decoding the DistinguishedName.  Sample hex of the certificate_authorities below is below - but where is the freaking exact spec for what the format of a DistinguishedName is?

Sample:

```
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
```

Comment: Have you tried using the definition of DistinguishedName from [RFC 2459](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2459.txt) which after all is about Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure, Certificate and CRL Profile. Sometimes "derived from" just means "is taken from"...

Comment: I don't see why you need to know. It's just opaque data that must match the content of an IssuerDN in a certificate presented in response, and that comes from the SubjectDN's of the certificates you trust. You don't care what's inside it.

Comment: @mki: I'll check that out - it may work.

Comment: @EJP: I care what's inside because I'm trying to parse it into a human-readable DN.